# How to display data at Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

i am new in Django and i want you help.  I have 3 model classes and and i want to connect them.

1) class Cityhall

```
cityhallname = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='cityhall name', blank=False)
```

2) class Employee

```
employeename = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='employee name', blank=False)
cityhallname = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='cityhall name', blank=False)
```

3) class jobs

At 3rd class i want when i choose a cityhall to filters me the employees. To bring me only employees who works for the chosen city hall.

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details to your question, so that others can understand it better. Consider adding your models and admin file.

Comment: You should not have `cityhallname` as a field on `Employee`, but have a `ForeignKey` to your `CityHall` model. Also you don't need a 3rd model if all you want to do is filter employees by city hall.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your relevant models to admin. Go through official documentation you can learn how to do that. [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/)